# Error when starting DaVinci Resolve in Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: libraries

I've installed DaVinci Resolve 14 on a fresh install of Ubuntu 17.04. It does kinda start, and by that I mean that it shows the first run splash screen, where it does a basic configuration and some minor setup questions, but when it comes to actually starting the program, it gets stuck on a frozen splash screen (I cannot see what it displays, for it copies whatever it is on the background), dubbed mutter-dialog. Someone on the Blackmagic forum suggested to start it from the terminal and see what error displays. By doing that it displays the following...

> ActCCMessage Already in Table: Code= 2282, Mode=  0, Level=  0, CmdKey= 8, Option= 0
>   ActCCMessage Already in Table: Code= c005, Mode= 13, Level=  1, CmdKey= -1, Option= 0
>   ActCCMessage Already in Table: Code= c006, Mode= 13, Level=  1, CmdKey= -1, Option= 0
>   ActCCMessage Already in Table: Code= c007, Mode= 13, Level=  1, CmdKey= -1, Option= 0
>   14.0b (#067)
>   Main thread starts: 40DE1040
>   [0x7f3240de1040] | Undefined            | INFO  | 2017-08-27 13:06:34,121 | --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
>   [0x7f3240de1040] | Undefined            | INFO  | 2017-08-27 13:06:34,122 | Loaded log config from /opt/resolve/configs/log-conf.xml
>   [0x7f3240de1040] | Undefined            | INFO  | 2017-08-27 13:06:34,122 | --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
>   *** Error in `./resolve': realloc(): invalid pointer: 0x0000000010c3faa0 ***
>   ======= Backtrace: =========
>   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x7908b)[0x7f322898208b]
>   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(realloc+0x3b0)[0x7f32289902b0]
>   /usr/lib/nvidia-375/libnvidia-ptxjitcompiler.so.375.66(+0x6c38f2)[0x7f312e3fb8f2]
>   /usr/lib/nvidia-375/libnvidia-ptxjitcompiler.so.375.66(+0x6b9b9b)[0x7f312e3f1b9b]
>   /usr/lib/nvidia-375/libnvidia-ptxjitcompiler.so.375.66(+0x6b7971)[0x7f312e3ef971]
>   /usr/lib/nvidia-375/libnvidia-ptxjitcompiler.so.375.66(+0xd83b3)[0x7f312de103b3]
>   /usr/lib/nvidia-375/libnvidia-ptxjitcompiler.so.375.66(+0x68f51b)[0x7f312e3c751b]
>   /usr/lib/nvidia-375/libnvidia-ptxjitcompiler.so.375.66(+0x6a216f)[0x7f312e3da16f]
>   /usr/lib/nvidia-375/libnvidia-ptxjitcompiler.so.375.66(+0xd9426)[0x7f312de11426]
>   /usr/lib/nvidia-375/libnvidia-ptxjitcompiler.so.375.66(+0xb7170)[0x7f312ddef170]
>   /usr/lib/nvidia-375/libnvidia-ptxjitcompiler.so.375.66(+0x6b5f9d)[0x7f312e3edf9d]
>   /usr/lib/nvidia-375/libnvidia-ptxjitcompiler.so.375.66(+0xbdfd2)[0x7f312ddf5fd2]
>   /usr/lib/nvidia-375/libnvidia-ptxjitcompiler.so.375.66(+0xc0391)[0x7f312ddf8391]
>   /usr/lib/nvidia-375/libnvidia-ptxjitcompiler.so.375.66(__cuda_CallJitEntryPoint+0xdcc)[0x7f312ddeeaec]
>   /usr/lib/nvidia-375/libnvidia-fatbinaryloader.so.375.66(fatBinaryCtl_Compile+0x302)[0x7f32185ac5c2]
>   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvidia-opencl.so.1(+0x1c1f92)[0x7f3213782f92]
>   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvidia-opencl.so.1(+0x1c2b13)[0x7f3213783b13]
>   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvidia-opencl.so.1(+0x1c31e3)[0x7f32137841e3]
>   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvidia-opencl.so.1(+0xbd277)[0x7f321367e277]
>   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvidia-opencl.so.1(+0xbdb1d)[0x7f321367eb1d]
>   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvidia-opencl.so.1(+0xbca9d)[0x7f321367da9d]
>   /opt/resolve/bin/../libs/libCrmSdk.so.2.0(FbcClInitialize+0x272)[0x7f322a7ab83c]
>   /opt/resolve/bin/../libs/libCrmSdk.so.2.0(CrmImpl_InitializeSDK+0x1f7)[0x7f322a7d15ee]
>   /opt/resolve/bin/../libs/libCrmSdk.so.2.0(CrmInitializeSDK+0xe)[0x7f322a7d0ab4]
>   ./resolve[0x35d210f]
>   ./resolve[0x719e65]
>   ./resolve(main+0x24f)[0x6fcaaf]
>   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf1)[0x7f32289293f1]
>   ./resolve[0x6fbab9]

The error seems be from an invalid pointer, but I have no idea how should I approach that. Can you please give me some ideas or recommendations of what can I do or what to  look for? Thanks in advance.